# Python multiprocessing with API

Tags: python, api, multiprocessing, google-colaboratory, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to collect data by using below python code on Google Colab

```
tickers = ['TSLA', 'NVTA', 'SQ', 'ROKU', 'CRSP', 'PRLB', 'Z', 'TWOU', 'WORK', 'TDOC','TWST', 'ZS', 'ICE', 'SNPS', 'XLNX', 'IRDM', 'FB', 'SYRS', 'PACB', 'SE',
           'EDIT', 'MCRB', 'CGEN', 'PSTG', 'PD', 'IOVA', 'ILMN', 'NTLA', 'MTLS', 'SPOT','NSTG', 'TSM', 'SPLK', 'VCYT', 'CERS', 'TWLO', 'HUYA', 'DOCU', 'SSYS', 'PINS']

df = pd.DataFrame({})
for i in range(len(tickers)) : 
  t = tickers[i]
  df1 = pd.read_excel('https://stockrow.com/api/companies/'+t+'/financials.xlsx?dimension=Q&section=Metrics&sort=desc')
  df = df.append(df1)
```

To save time, I tried to use multiprocessing.

```
def processInput(i):
  t =tickers[i]
  return pd.read_excel('https://stockrow.com/api/companies/'+t+'/financials.xlsx?dimension=Q&section=Metrics&sort=desc')
inputs = range(len(tickers))
pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
results = pool.map(processInput, inputs)
summary = pd.concat(results)
```

This works fine, however when I change to processes=4 , I am getting error.
I don't think it is the limit of the CPU as I am using Google Colab and the code is quite simple. I have a feeling that the API doesn't allow multiple access at the same time.
Can you please advise me and solve the issue? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm I am also getting an error on my 6/12 CPU desktop (works with =2, fails with =4, same as you)

Comment: It seems that sometimes the stockrow website just returns an Excel file that Pandas doesn't know how to parse. And for some reason it happens more often with more processes

Comment: It could just be that the website is doing it on purpose to block a single IP from downloading too much data too fast. I tried doing it with 10 processes and the following tickers failed: 1 failed
3 failed
4 failed
5 failed
6 failed
8 failed
13 failed
16 failed
29 failed
37 failed. 
The rest succeeded. Tried running it again and 1 failed
2 failed
3 failed
4 failed
8 failed
29 failed
31 failed

Comment: do we have multiprocessing within Colab!? That would be awesome